# Higher textual criticism resources

Tags: pali-canon, texts, pali-language

I would like some resources on textual criticism of the pali canon and other ancient buddhist works generally considered to be trustworthy. These should include works from all three traditions if possible.

Be it via blog, video or audio I don't care.

Theologian Robert M. Price sets a good example example of the level of rigor I'm looking for here in this podcast.

https://youtu.be/AyQPVytxbGI

In other words, accessible to the lay person who doesn't speak in this case, Greek or Aramaic, but not dumbed down and pedantic to the point of being patronizing.

Answer (score 2):

There's not much of the kind of critical criticism of the kind that Price is giving in his talk. Scholars of Buddhism are largely in love with their subject. It is something I have complained about on my blog. Academia is still in the stage of trying to accurately describe what Buddhism is and generally likes what it sees. Few scholars are engaged with what it is *not* or with the conflicts and contradictions within the tradition.

Perhaps the only prominent scholar who is actively critical is Greg Schopen though much of his criticism is based on the conflict between archaeological evidence and textual evidence. His collection of essays "*Bones, Stones, and Buddhist Monks*" is worth reading. This video [The Buddha as Businessman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GeZGFvbDzo) shows him giving a talk that gives a good idea of his approach.

Apart from [my blog](http://jayarava.blogspot.co.uk/) there are a few online references which are openly critical of Buddhist ideas and practices.

- The [Secular Buddhist Association](http://secularbuddhism.org/);
- Ted Meissner's  [Secular Buddhist podcast](http://secularbuddhism.org/category/podcasts/) (now seems to have merged with the SBA),
- [Meaningness](http://meaningness.com/) (by a Buddhist and sometimes about Buddhism, but with a much broader scope).
- Glenn Wallis's [Speculative Non-Buddhism](http://speculativenonbuddhism.com/) is a rather acquired taste, but nothing if not critical. Strong influence from Post-modernism and Marxism.
- [Richard K Payne](https://rkpayne.wordpress.com/) is an academic who is frequently critical of modernist developments in Buddhism.
- There's also [Smiling Buddha Cabaret](https://enlightenmentward.wordpress.com/) focus on feminist themes.
- I have not reviewed Matthew O'Connell's [Post-Traditional Buddhism](http://posttraditionalbuddhism.com/) seems to be in a similar vein (he's influenced by Wallis).

There may be more. But this lot will keep you busy for a while. There are a number of websites which are aimed at critical approaches to practice. This is not really my area of expertise, but one can look into the phrase "dharma overground" for example.

Comment: Thanks so much, Jayarava Atwood for so much information I can really sink my teeth into.

Comment: Great set of links. @user117619 Ajahn Sujato [has a reasonably detailed challenge of the work of Greg Schopen](https://sujato.wordpress.com/2011/01/22/the-ironic-assumptions-of-gregory-schopen/) on his blog. Just a counter point to the Buddha as a Businessman talk which is enjoyable.

Comment: Yes. See my response to Sujato: https://sujato.wordpress.com/2011/01/22/the-ironic-assumptions-of-gregory-schopen/#comment-14663